# Multiple threading - Task.WhenAll when download blob storage files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code that downloads blob file to a string. It works fine but just very poor performance. It takes about 50 seconds to process 500 files.
`

```
           try
            {
                var sourceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);
                var foundItems = sourceClient.FindBlobsByTags("Client = 'TEST'").ToList();

                foreach (var blob in foundItems)
                {
                    var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobClient(blob.BlobName);
                    BlobDownloadResult download = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
                    string downloadedData = download.Content.ToString();
                    myList.Add(downloadedData);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");`
            }
    `
```

I tried with multi threads for the code but it still takes about 25 seconds to process 500 files.

```
           var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
           var tasks = new List<Task>();
            try
            {
                var sourceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);
                var foundItems = sourceClient.FindBlobsByTags("Client = 'TEST'").ToList();

                foreach (var blob in foundItems)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                            var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobClient(blob.BlobName);
                            BlobDownloadResult download = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
                            string downloadedData = download.Content.ToString();
                            myList.Add(downloadedData);
;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            semaphore.Release();
                        }
                    }));
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
```

I'm pretty new to C#, am I doing anything wrong with multi-threading? what's the fastest way to read file from blob storage?

Note:  the following line of code causes the most delay.

```
BlobDownloadResult download = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
```

Comment: What takes the longest is the act of transferring the data (so basically I/O), do you have the bandwidth available to transfer the data any faster?

Comment: BTW what is `myList`?

Comment: I'd do some analysis to see how the time is being spent. I suspect the majority of the time is spent doing file I/O

Comment: @GuruStron just list of string.  List<string> myList = new List<string>();

Comment: As for wrongly using threading - 1) No need to wrap into `Task,Run` - this can have negative effect on performance (though doubt that in this case) 2) potentially 50 parallel download tasks is too much and will not  have positive effect on the runtime 3) Consider using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or other build in functions.

Comment: @TheBatman Most time spent on DownloadContentAsync();

Comment: @Blue `List` is not thread safe collection, consider using `ConcurrentBag` or other from `System.Collections.Concurrent` .

Comment: @orhtej2 What bandwidth are you referring to? The limitation on Azure blob storage side? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two biggest performance problems with your code are:

- Don't wrap that download task in `Task.Run`, you're just using thread pool threads for no reason.
- Stop switching contexts for no reason, use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your `await` calls.

A third problem, minor in comparison:

- You're corrupting your memory by pushing to a `List<>` from multiple threads. Use a proper concurrent container, like `ConcurrentBag<>`. Edit: in fact I'm not even convinced you need the list, use the return value of `Task.WhenAll` to gather the results instead of doing result gathering by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not understanding about wrap download task in Task.Run. Do you mean move the download task outside of the try or remove the Task.Run?

Comment: Remove `Task.Run`, the code you're running is already multi-threaded (backed by operating system threads, in fact).

Comment: So do I change Task.run to New task?  Like this tasks.Add(new Task(async () =>?

Comment: No, `Task` doesn't have a `Task` constructor, hopefully for obvious reasons (ie you know, because if you have a task, why make a new task?). An easy way to get a task from your async code is to create a local function `async Task helper() { /* your await code here */ } tasks.Add(helper());`